# Problemas com Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web.config

Estou com dificuldade para utilizar vários web.config no meu sistema.
No meu `web.config` principal eu tenho a seguinte configuração:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="BASE_URL" value="/mvc/" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

E no meu arquivo `web.release.config` eu tenho a seguinte modificação:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="BASE_URL" value="/mvc" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Porém, quando eu chamo a propriedade `BASE_URL`, ele está me retornando o valor do config principal e não no modificador, mesmo eu usando a configuração Release para fazer o build do projeto.

Estou utilizando C# MVC4 no VS2013

Answer (score 1):

Existem três configuração de Web.config:

- Web.config - É utilizada em qualquer situação do Configuration Manager (Debug/Release) enquanto você estiver rodando sua aplicação diretamente pelo Visual Studio.
- Web.Debug.config - É utilizada para a publicação, quando o Configuration Manager está em Debug
- Web.Release.config - É utilizada para a publicação, quando o Configuration Manager está em Release

Portanto você pode conseguir três situações em que suas variáveis podem ser alteradas, eu particularmente acho isto vantajoso em situações que lido com endereços locais, a configuração Web.config aponta para um local físico na minha máquina (ex.: C:/Teste/), e as outras apontam para os respectivos endereços virtuais do IIS (ex.: /Debug/Arquivos/ para Debug e /Release/Arquivos/ para Release).

Answer (score 0):

Vá no Menu BUILD -> Configuration Manager.

No combo "Active solution configuration", altere para release. Verifique se o arquivo .config que será utilizado é de fato o web.config.release.

Comment: Obrigado pelo dica Thiago, mas eu j[a tinha feito isso, descobri que os web.config diferenciais só funcionam quando publicamos o projeto, mas valeu a intenção